# Understanding a command in C++

Tags: c++, command

I am new to C++, I am trying to understand a piece of code written in C++, here `px` is an integer, Could please tell me, if the following line is
doing something like `if` statement. Is it saying if `pos.x`  is equal to `residues[n-1]` put it in `px` or vice versa?

```
px = (res->pos.x == residues[n-1]->pos.x) & (res->pos.x == residues[n+1]->pos.x);
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Which part of the expression don't you understand?

Comment: What it does is making a AND on two conditions. If pos.x differs in both results and residues on both tests then px will be either 1 or 0.

Comment: `px` will be  true if `res->pos.x` equals to `residues[n-1]->pos.x` **and** also it is equals  `residues[n+1]->pos.x`. In this particular case `&` will produce the same result as `&&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` in this expression is a bitwise AND operation.
It takes the result of the comparison in both of the parentheses and does a bitwise AND on them.
In the left parentheses, it compares the `x` value of `res` to the `x` value of `residues[n-1]`. A true result is pretty much 1 and false is 0, so it pretty much evaluates to either 1 or 0.
In the right parentheses, you have the same comparison but at index `n+1` now. Same things apply.

If both parentheses are true, the bitwise AND evaluates to 1 (true), else 0 (false).
px is probably an integer that is either 1 or 0 and it will hold 1 if both of the comparisons were true in the expression, otherwise it will hold 0. (It acts as a Boolean)

Comment: Thank you very much